# Floor Summation Series

Tags: number-theory

> What is
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}   \bigg\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}}\bigg\rfloor?$$

This is an interesting question I thought of. The values are
$$1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 14, 16, 20,...$$
for the first few values of $n$, but I am stuck there.. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW: http://oeis.org/A006218